# Sounds play delay wrong

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, media

I am writing simple metronome component using Flex + AS3. I want it playing 'tick1' sound after, for example, each 500 millisecond and each 4th time plays another sound 'tick2'. But actually delay between sound is not equivalent - sometimes lesser, sometimes greater a bit. I testing it on latest Chrome.

Here my code:

```
//Somewhere here button bound to the 'toggle' function

import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.media.SoundTransform;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;

private var bpm:Number = 120; //2 bit per second, delay=500ms
private var period:Number = 4;
private var timer:Timer = new Timer(bpm, period);

[Embed(source='sounds/1.mp3')]
private var tickSound1Class:Class;
private var tickSound1:Sound;

[Embed(source='sounds/2.mp3')]
private var tickSound2Class:Class;
private var tickSound2:Sound;

private var trans:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(1);

private function init():void {
    ....

    tickSound1 = new tickSound1Class() as Sound;
    tickSound2 = new tickSound2Class() as Sound;

    update();


    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimerEvent);

    ....
}

private function update():void {
    timer.delay = 1000 * 60/bpm;
    timer.repeatCount = 0;
}

private function toggle():void {
    if (timer.running) {
        timer.reset();
        startStopButton.label = "Start";
    } else {
        update();
        timer.start();
        startStopButton.label = "Stop";
    }
}

private function onTimerEvent(event:TimerEvent):void {
    var t:Timer = event.currentTarget as Timer;

    if (t.currentCount % period == 0)
        tickSound1.play(0, 0, trans);
    else
        tickSound2.play(0, 0, trans);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two main reasons:

1. It is known that `Timer` object in Flash Player is inaccurate, delay between it's fires fluctuates.
2. `Sound.play()` method also introduces some delay before the sound actually starts to play, and theoretically this delay can fluctuate. The delay is especially noticeable in PPAPI version of Flash Player being used in Chrome.

There are several solutions. I would suggest one of these:

1. Use pre-composed sound of the whole metronome cycle (tick1-pause1-tick2-pause2) and just loop it using the second argument of `Sound.play()` method;
2. use dynamic sound generation.

The second option is more flexible but is more difficult to implement. Basicaly, you'll need to create a new instance of `Sound` object, subscribe to it's `SAMPLE_DATA` event and call it's `play()` method. In the handler you'll check `event.position / 44.1`, which will give you current position of sound generation in ms. Then, if you decide that it's time to play tick1 or tick2 sound, you'll call `tickN.extract(event.data, ...)`, where `tickN` is tick1 or tick2 `Sound` object, or write the silence otherwise.

You can read more about dynamic sound generation [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/dynamic_sound_generation.html).

Also, notice that when you call `Sound.play()` it returns a `SoundChannel` object, which has the `position` property. Is it a position in ms of a sound that is being played (*not generated*) at the moment, and it is accurate. So, using this property, you can come up with the third approach: create a `Sound` object and setup a `SAMPLE_DATA` handler like in the dynamic sound generation solution, but write the silence (zeros) to the `event.data` object inside the handler all the time. This is needed to obtain a sound channel without actually playing a sound. Then, use high frame rate (60 FPS) and a `Timer` with the smallest possible delay (1 ms). Each time the `Timer` fires, check `soundChannel.position` to determine whether it is time to play the tick sound, and, if it so, just play it like you're doing in your example. This approach is likely to solve the problem of the `Timer` inaccuracy, but it cannot deal with the delay caused by `tickSound.play()` method.

Comment: THank you. I decided to use 2nd approach. Ittakes some time for research how to sample and un-sample sounds but it seems the best solution, because I don't want to use server-side pregenerated sounds.

Comment: You're welcome :) Note that there is lower and upper limits of 2048 samples (approx. 50 ms) and 8192 samples (approx. 190 ms) that you can pass within single SAMPLE_DATA event, so, in some cases you'll need to slpit your tick sound and write it during several consecutive events.

Comment: The reason is that it can happen that current event.position is earlier than the time of next tick, but (event.position + 2048) is later. You'll write A = (tickTime * 44.1 - event.position) samples of silence, then B = (2048 - A) samples of tick sound starting from it's beginning. And then, in the next sample data event, C = (tickSound.length * 44.1 - B) samples of tick sound starting from is't B'th sample and again D = (2048 - C) samples of silence (1 sample of silence = 2 zero floats).

Comment: Using this approach, you can choose any size of sound chunk, not necessarily 2048 samples. Just replace 2048 in the previous comment with any size between 2048 and 8192 samples :) It's even better to use smth larger than 2048, as larger chunk sizes lead to better performance (and higher latency, but it matters only in applications that generate sound based on real-time user input).